# Create 3 Multiple JSON Objects from a single JSON API Return that has "key1": "value1;value2;value3" style encoding

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, n8n

I have been looking around a lot, and can't find a simple answer to my problem, I have seen how to do searching and things with LINQ to JSON (that seems to complex for my needs).

I am using n8n.io to try to execute a "WebHook Post" -> Function call -> Split to Batch (1) -> API Call

I have a JSON Object like this

```js
$json = {
  "_id": "627bd2378b8bbe5c27a23669",
  "firstName": "John;Maria;Bruce",
  "lastName": "Doe;Phenix;Mclean",
}
```

I need to send each of these as 3 individual JSON objects to another webhook

I am trying to figure out a for loop that could take `$json` and turn it into `$json[0]`, `$json[1]`, `$json[2]`

Where

```js
$json[0] = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
}

$json[1] = {
  "firstName": "Maria",
  "lastName": "Phenix",
}

$json[2] = 
  "firstName": "Bruce",
  "lastName": "Mclean",
}
```

I am having the hardest time finding the simplest and quickest way to go from A -> B any advice n8n.io allows me to take the $json.body from a previous step and process it with a javascript function?

Hoping there is some built-in method that can handle this translation in a step or two inside a for loop in Javascript.

```js
//iterate through the combined JSON Object
for (var k of $json) {
  //grab the row and split the string into 3 
  String.split($json[k]);
  //Create a $newObj with a full set of data in each index
}
return $newObj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @metdodrbic for pointing me in the right direction.

His code worked 100%

I did have to edit the $json to $json.body because of the peculiar way n8n.io returns the JSON object from a previous step into the "function" block

```js
const firstNames = $json.body.firstName.split(';');
const lastNames = $json.body.lastName.split(';');
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++) {
  result.push({firstName: firstNames[i], lastName: lastNames[i]})  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with n8n but if you can use javascript to process `$json`, then you can split the keys of specific properties and then concat them back with for loop like so:

```js
const firstNames = $json.firstName.split(';');
const lastNames = $json.lastName.split(';');
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++) {
  result.push({firstName: firstNames[i], lastName: lastNames[i]})  
}
```

Above code assumes that both `firstName` and `lastName` inside `$json` has the same amount of semicolon separated values. If one of the two can have more values than another, then I would suggest using `Math.max` to find the one with most values and use that one in for loop condition

Comment: No you are right, even if they are blank (just the delimiters with nothing there) they always match the same number. So for this instance Math. max isn't necessary.. but that is a cool thing I will remember for situations that require it.